# Java - Object Array - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I was doing a BFS problem where I had to find the shortest path from one node to another node using java. Each node has only one connection. But for some reason, when I try adding new nodes on-to a Queue, it returns a null-pointer exception.

here's my code (Java):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Main{

    static Friend[] friends = new Friend[10000]; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        for(int a = 0; a < N; a++){
            String[] get = r.readLine().split(" ");
            int A = Integer.parseInt(get[0]);
            int B = Integer.parseInt(get[1]);
            friends[A] = new Friend(A);
            friends[B] = new Friend(B);
            friends[A].partner = new Friend(B);
        }
        while(true){
            String[] get = r.readLine().split(" ");
            int A = Integer.parseInt(get[0]);
            int B = Integer.parseInt(get[1]);
            if(A == 0 && B == 0)break;
            BFS(friends[A], friends[B]);
        }
    }

    private static void BFS(Friend a, Friend b){
        Queue<Friend> Q = new LinkedList<Friend>();
        Queue<Integer> DQ = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Q.add(a);
        DQ.add(-1);
        while(!Q.isEmpty()){
            Friend f = Q.poll();
            int dist = DQ.poll();
            if(f.ID == b.ID){
                System.out.println("YES " +  dist);
                return;
            }
            Q.add(f.partner); //getting a Null-Pointer exception here.
            DQ.add(dist + 1);
        }
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
}

class Friend{
    int ID;
    Friend partner = null;
    public Friend(int id){
        ID = id;
    }
}
```

Sample Input

```
6
1 2
2 3
3 1
10 11
100 10
11 100
1 100
2 3
0 0
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the input that got you this exception?

Comment: @GregoryBasior added sample input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  Everytime that you are adding a new friend into your friend array, you are overwriting the previous one.  What this means is that when you first add number 1, it has a partner of 2.  But, when you add 3 1, you overwrite 1 and it now has no partner, so if you change the code to only add it if it is null, and to point its partner towards the actual other object instead of a new one, then all of the pointers will maintain their integrity:

```
            if(friends[A]==null)
                friends[A] = main.new Friend(A);
            if(friends[B]==null)
                friends[B] = main.new Friend(B);
            friends[A].partner = friends[B];
```

But, the BFS method now has an infinite loop if there is no path, as in the case of 1 --> 100, so we need to break out of there if we have gotten back to our original node, so we need to add in:

```
          if(f.ID == a.ID && dist > -1) break;
```